# problems with identityuser role asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

[image]

[image]

What do I do to correct this?
I am trying to implement roles. My db context was formed in a scaffolding of the database, so I don't know which class I should derivate.

[image]

Comment: do mark the answer below as the correct answer if it helped you. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is the type you are passing at .AddRoles(), it should be `IdentityRole` not IdentityUser.

Use the code below;

```
.AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
```

Comment: thanks i will try this